# Cloudformation - Template attributes that allow users to use an email address or phone number as their “username” to sign up and sign in

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a Cognito User Pool through Cloudformation but I'm unable to define a template that allow users to use an email address or phone number as their “username” to sign up and sign in to my application.

I have created an AWS::Cognito::UserPool setting phone_number and email as AliasAttributes, but when I try to sign up with an email or phone number as username I get a message telling that the username cannot match an email or phone number format.

[image: cognito]

I can define that through AWS Management Console (image above). Does anyone know how I can achieve that through Cloudformation template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an answer posted by AWS on the AWS Developer Forums:

> Currently this setting is not available in Cloudformation template but will be added in future releases.

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=259548&tstart=0

Answer (score 3):

I'm from the future!

```
    UserPool:
        Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
        Properties:
            UsernameAttributes: 
                - email
```

Found it [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=259349)

Thought I'd post it here for posterity.